# How well does a BCM4321 bluetooth work?

Tags: 11.04, bluetooth

I want to upgrade my HP DV6000's wireless card with a BCM4321, but I already have problems getting my BCM4311 to work. Is the BCM4321 card supported? How would I set it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're planning to upgrade a card yourself, I'd personally opt for an Intel wireless chipset. Intel has an unrivalled record for providing drivers for their WiFi cards. You can  all but guarantee it'll work on Linux.

I didn't know the BCM4321 had onboard BT. I've no idea if it works. As for WiFi, I think it's covered by the newer bcm80211 (renamed to something else in 2.6.29) which works very well for the brcm4313 in this laptop. You need at least Natty for this to work well.

On a side note, if wireless transport speeds are important to you, check to make sure it's not hard-limited. The 4313 is limited to a pathetic 72MB/s. Fine for browsing, painful for moving 20gig files around.

Comment: Intel wireless tends to require binary firmware, some of which isn't distributable (most is these days). It's got a good track record of working, but be warned you may need to grab the firmware in odd situations.